# PHP array in wordpress returns NULL

Tags: php, wordpress

I have array with an another array. and I'm want to get the first element, but var_dump returns null. I tried to find my answer from the other questions but couldn't. Here is my code...

```
global $wp_registered_sidebars,
var_dump($wp_registered_sidebars)
```

returns

```
array(size=1)'sidebar-109' => array(size=8)
      'name' => string 'Sections' (length=8)
      'id' => string 'sidebar-109' (length=11)
      'description' => string '' (length=0)
      'class' => string '' (length=0)
      'before_widget' => string '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">' (length=34)
      'after_widget' => string '</li>' (length=6)
      'before_title' => string '<h2 class="widgettitle">' (length=24)
      'after_title' => string '</h2>' (length=6)
```

and

```
var_dump($wp_registered_sidebars[0]);
```

returns NULL.

Comment: Use [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) if you having trouble accessing that arbitrary key.

Comment: what an easy decision. I don't know about that function. it works. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

That should probably be `$wp_registered_sidebars['sidebar-109']`, as it's an associative array, not an indexed one.

I personally prefer `var_export`, as I find it makes these things clearer, but that's a matter of personal taste, I guess.